# How to extract a column from a windows output?

Tags: windows, command-line

We have
    C:\Temp>wc -l c:\temp\files.txt | tee count.txt

```
8 c:\temp\files.txt
```

We like to get the first column (eg 8).

How do we extract that output number from the console and count.txt for use in other conditional check in our simple windows script?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solved it myself with the following:

cut -f1 -d" " count.txt